# View vote counts instead of score as default (for established users)

Tags: support, feature-request

As an [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) you have the privilege to "view vote counts instead of the total voting scores... You can view the vote counts by clicking on the score of a post. This will break the score into upvotes and downvotes."

Is it possible to make *this* "broken score" vote view the *default* view, so you do not have to click on each score? It gives you much more information on the quality of the question/answer.

I am *not* asking for changing the privilige policy, just for making this view *default* for established users. (Or user-configurable.)

Comment: No, this is not an option, as has been stated repeatedly, because the query too calculate the votes is to computationally expensive.

Comment: Do you mean that you keep the calculated score stored in the database, whilst the plus and minus votes are calculated ad hoc on request? Wow! So why not to store all the three sums?

Comment: It's been asked of them a number of times.  They have no elaborated to my knowledge, simply saying that this isn't going to happen.

Comment: Still I do not understand why the total sum is not expensive, whilst the two partial sums (which the total one is the sum of) are considered as computationally expensive.

Comment: if they store the sum separately it takes one request on each voting to update it. if there were 2 it would take 2 requests. So on a page with 200 questions that's twice as much work i guess

Comment: Because the entire system was specifically designed to optimize for the former from the very start, and not designed to be optimized for the latter.

Comment: I don't want to hijack the original question, but is there a reason that the breakdown of up/down votes is a privileged operation - i.e. why can't any user just click on the vote count to get the breakdown? Is that just to have an extra privilege level as an incentive for contributors who are motivated by that, or is there another reason? Added the comment to this question as it was the only one which came up in my search on this topic.

Comment: @mc110 It's available through the API, and [there is a user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) that does it all for you. The vote counts are retrieved right now through the API for 1k+ users, they are not embedded directly into the response. You could make a user script that clicked them all automatically, but then you're going to go through your API limits fast.

Comment: Regarding the expensiveness of the query metioned by @Servy there is a [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286897/show-the-vote-split-by-default) question that explains why